# Ok to put Exception in EventArgs?

Tags: c#, events

I'm building a messenger library, and I have a question about how properly to report specific errors to the user.

The main Messenger class has two states - logged in, and logged out.

Errors that occur internally can cause the client to logout.

For example, a DisconnectException (if a SocketException occurs internally), or a ChallengeFailedException if the client is unable to complete a challenge issued by the messenger server.

Is it ok (or recommended) to pass the exception to the user in the LogoutEventArgs ? for instance - LogoutEventArgs.Exception

Or is there a more ideal way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the exception isn't expected (i.e., it really is an *exceptional* circumstance) then you should probably just let the exception be thrown so that the user can use a *catch* statement to deal with any specific exception types.

**If the exception is thrown from another thread**, you can wrap it in another exception and throw it on the calling thread.

If it is an expected, common error condition then it depends on what the user is supposed to do in that case. Something like an enumeration or a custom *Error* class might be better than just sticking the exception in the `EventArgs` object. The custom object *can* include a reference to the `Exception` object as well.

Comment: I added a suggestion in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I have a class that swallows some known exceptions such as sql server time out.  This is so my clients don't need to deal with this, my class catches it and returns an error enum.
I event out the caught exceptions solely so my clients can opt to log them.  I don't want my class to have logging dependencies.